# use scanner to store lines to an array

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need to copy the data which I have and then paste it to the java Eclipse Console output window, this data contains some lines and there is a word in each line. I don't know how many lines it has.
How could I store the lines in an array? I tried this code but after pasting the data, I should press the keyboard **Enter** key two times. It also stores the even lines (Not all lines). How may I fix it? Thanks

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SCAN {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(s.hasNextLine()){
            String line = s.nextLine();
            if(line.length() > 0) {
                lines.add(s.nextLine());
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(lines);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change   `lines.add(s.nextLine());` to   `lines.add(line);`

Whats Happening here is you are using `nextLine()` twice.

So first Line got read and stored to `line` but after that it reads second one which is stored to `ArrayList` so first line which you have stored won't be there in `ArrayList`.

> I should press the keyboard Enter key two times.

*Yes You have to because you are breaking loop when you don't have line.*

---

If you want to enter Specific lines you can use counter for Number of lines.

You can prompt by `Scanner` to insert specific value for counter.

```
    int i=0;
    while(s.hasNextLine()){
        String line = s.nextLine();i++;
        if(line.length() > 0) {
            lines.add(line);
        } else {
            //don't add empty Line
        }
    if(i==2)break;
    }
```

Comment: `if(line.length() > 0) {...` ? Sorry!! I didn't get you

Comment: i mean when I use this code I should paste Enter Key two times to get the result, how could I fix it? I think I should replace if(line.length() > 0) {... with another code.Thanks

Comment: No you have to press Enter twice as first for Empty line and second to break loop.(_according to your code_).If my answer has solved your problem you can accept it. :)Thnks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Scanner read=new Scanner(System.in);

for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    array[i]=read.next();
    array[i]+=read.nextLine();
}
```